# Правильная архитектура для WebApi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, архитектура, entity-framework-core

Всем привет!

Думаю над тем как стоит организовать в архитектуру в одном приложении.

Приведу упрощённые примеры, для простоты:

1. У меня есть модели данных для заказа и доставки (например, Order и
   Delivery).
2. Для работы с ними на уровне БД я добавил репозитории
   (OrderRepository и DeliveryRepository). Они содержат классические методы CRUD для сущностей.
3. Для реализации
   бизнес-логики добавил соответствующие сервисы (OrderService и DeliveryService).
   Сервисы используют репозитории и выполняют необходимые манипуляции с данными в соответствии
   бизнес правилами.
4. Для взаимодействия с внешним миром добавил контроллеры, которые вызывают необходимые методы у сервисов.

Основная проблема которую я сейчас не знаю как лучше решить - как организовать транзакционность при выполнении методов сервисов.

Например, вызывается Create у OrderService он должен создать заказ и доставку для него.
Соответственно логика по работе с заказами содержится в нём, а логика по работе с доставками содержится в DeliveryService.

Поэтому получается примерно вот такой код:

```
    public async Task<int> CreateAsync(Order order)
    {
        // проверяем возможность создания заказа с указанными параметрами
        await ValidateOrderAsync(order);

        // создаём заказ
        var orderId = await orderRepository.CreateAsync(order);

        // создаём доставку для заказа
        await deliveryService.Create(orderId, order.Delivery);

        // возвращаем идентификатор созданного заказа
        return orderId;
    }
```

При такой реализации мне сильно не нравится, что может быть ситуация при которой создастся заказ, но не создастся доставка для него (например, параметры доставки не прошли валидацию).
Поэтому хотелось бы такие действия выполнять в одну транзакцию: либо мы создаём все что от нас требуется, либо не создаём ничего и возвращаем ошибку.

Как вариант решения есть паттерн Unit of Work реализовав который у меня был бы один класс UnitOfWork с моими репозиториями, в котором есть метод Save, который можно было бы вызвать в конце метода и тогда как раз всё сохранится или нет.
Для этой ситуации это действительно бы отработало как надо.

Но что тогда делать в ситуации, когда OrderService в свою очередь вызывается другим сервисом, тогда получается, что в этой ситуации я не могу вызывать метод сохранения, так как сохранение будет вызывать вызывающий сервис.
Т.е. в каких-то ситуациях я могу вызывать метод Save, а в каких-то нет.
Я конечно могу добавить в параметры метода флаг, который определяет нужно ди мне вызывать сохранения в этом методе.

Но хотелось бы понять как правильно поступать в таких ситуациях.
Возможно есть какие-то базовые подходы, чтобы не изобретать свой велосипед.

Пример упрощённый, в общем случае сущностей и сервисов может быть много и операций соответственно тоже (изменение, удаление и т.д.)

Comment: Для таких случаев есть транзакции БД.

Comment: @aepot Но тогда и бизнес-логику придётся переносить в БД, так ведь? )

Comment: @CrazyElf это уж как видит художник.

Comment: @aepot Автор явно хочет бизнес-логику в сервисах на C#

Comment: @CrazyElf тогда нужно считать существование в базе недозаполненного заказа нормальным. А логику, связанную с его обработкой надо научить это состояние заказа воспринимать правильно. Как в таск-трекерах, есть таск, есть его состояние, есть транзишны для этого состояния. Для каждого состояния свой набор допустимых транзишнов. Транзишн меняет состояние таска. Теперь я не же не глупости предлагаю рассматривать? Каждый транзишн - это транзакция.

Comment: @aepot Вот и оформите это всё как ответ, я так понимаю, автор и хочет понять, как правильно сделать как бы транзакции, но не на уровне БД, а на уровне сервисов. Хотя без соответствующих статусов объектов в БД тоже, наверное, не обойтись.

Comment: @aepot, да в первую очередь конечно бы не хотелось смешивать разные уровни приложения. Т.е. работа с данными в репозиториях, бизнес-логика в сервисах. С недозаполнеными заказами тоже не хотелось бы работать. Т.е. клиент либо создаёт полноценный заказ, либо ему говорят, что заказ нельзя создать из-за определенной ошибки. Плюс такая ситуация с заказом - это частный случай, а так вообще могут быть и другие ситуации, когда разные сервисы друг с другом взаимодействуют.

Comment: @CrazyElf я не особо компетентен в предметной области вопроса, чтобы писать подобного уровня ответы. Все что выше - предположния, а не решение. Вы можете оформить ответ используя то что я написал, я только за.

Comment: `создаёт полноценный заказ, либо ему говорят, что заказ нельзя создать из-за определенной ошибки` не смешивайте валидацию данных и их реальную обработку - это разные операции, и они результируют в разные ошибки. Бизнес-логика может пропускать то, что может непропускать валидация. А может быть наоборот, как в вашем случае, типа клиент ввел все верно, но при коммите в базу "что-то пошло не так". :)

Comment: Как я вижу, у сервиса должна быть возможность удалить уже созданный заказ, если что-то пошло не так. В сервисе будет своя "транзакция" с `try`-`catch` и разными проверками. Всё ок - хорошо, не всё ок - чистим за собой всё, что насоздавали. Ну, куда-то в эту степь. Я и сам не люблю бизнес-логику в БД запихивать, `SQL` - ужасный язык, на мой взгляд )

Comment: @aepot, да всё верно, создание доставки может завершится ошибкой по разным причинам (бизнес-правила, ошибка при подключении и т.д.). Поэтому и хотелось бы использовать какой-то аналог транзакции, что если произошла любая ошибка, то мы откатываем создание заказа.

Comment: Вот и работайте с этими двумя слоями логики отдельно. Научитесь выплевывать ошибки и оттуда и отсюда попутно сохраняя целостность данных, то есть откатывать свою незаконченную сервисную "транзакцию". Удалять записи в БД не советую, можно случайно удалить то, информация о чем потребуется в будущем (например при разборе инцидента, речь же о деньгах), а вот помечать на удаление - можно вполне себе нормально.

Comment: да, я вообще надеялся, что есть какой-то общепринятый подход для таких ситуаций. всё-таки такое разделение приложений по слоям - нормальная практика и по идее  многие должны были с таким сталкиваться.

Comment: в целом мне вариант с Unit of Work и передачей флага сохранять/не сохранять нравится. тут не надо переживать за целостность данных т.к. сохранение в БД будет только в конце. но повторюсь ещё раз не хотелось свой велосипед изобретать.

Comment: Каждый велосипед кто-то когда-то изобрел :) ничего в этом страшного нет. Смотрите в сторону, как это потом можно будет расширять и переделывать. Чтобы не икалось в будущем.

Comment: у вас доставка бывает без заказа? Какие могут быть причины создания сервисов/репозтториев для доставки? Если доставка - это просто что то, что сопутсвует заказу, что может она должна быть в репозитории заказа?

Answer (score 0):

Концептуально вам нужно чтобы:

1. когда метод в сервисе (типа `CreateAsync`) начинается, начиналась транзакция в БД (на практике - нужно открыть соединение с БД и начать транзакцию)
2. вызовы к БД, которые инициированы во время выполнения сервиса через репозитории, использовали ту же транзакцию (на практике это означает, что они должны использовать то же соединение)
3. если вызов к `CreateAsync` завершился успешно - транзакция должна фиксироваться (по англ. commit) (при этом все операции, которые делали отдельные репозитории будут зафиксированы).
4. если вызов к `CreateAsync` завершился исключением, то транзакция должна откатываться.

Самый простой способ это реализовать без усилий это использовать spring .net. Я не специалист в .net, то управление транзакциями в spring [поддерживает ADO .NET](https://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/transaction.html#motivations) (я так понимаю entity framework это его часть):

> Spring fills the gap - it provides declarative transaction management if you are using local ADO.NET or System.Transactions (the most popular) or other data access technologies

Выглядеть это будет очень просто:

```
    [Transaction]
    public async Task<int> CreateAsync(Order order)
    {
        // проверяем возможность создания заказа с указанными параметрами
        await ValidateOrderAsync(order);

        // создаём заказ
        var orderId = await orderRepository.CreateAsync(order);

        // создаём доставку для заказа
        await deliveryService.Create(orderId, order.Delivery);

        // возвращаем идентификатор созданного заказа
        return orderId;
    }
```

Ну и нужно сконфигурировать spring, чтоб репозитории использовали тот же transaction manager (в доке это все описано более чем хорошо).

Можно, конечно, сделать это и вручную, если интересно, то допишу.

Comment: Тащить в проект спринг чисто для поддержки транзакций выглядит как оверкилл.

Comment: Ну это способ "без усилий". Если есть "родной" способ сделать то же, то лучше использовать его. Можно и вручную реализовать используя тот же принцип, что в spring (но без DI контейнера), только самое главное.

Comment: ну, "без усилий" ваш вари ант сложно назвать, так как вы предлагаете не просто переписать уровень доступа к данным (так как автор сейчас использует EF Core), но и сменить платформу, ведь spring поддерживает старый фреймоворк 4.6, но не поддерживает (я не нашел по крайней мере) .net core

Comment: Фактически, вы предложили притащить слой доступа в БД прямо в сервисы. Ну, такое :)

Comment: @CrazyElf нет. В сервисах определяются исключительно границы транзакций, причем 1. в широком смысле (т.е. не обязательно с БД) 2. декларативно с помощью атрибутов. Слой доступа к данным в репозиториях, только они делают запросы в БД. Да и это не я придумал :) Я тут всего лишь описал (коряво и недостаточно подробно), как это делается в спринге (а это дефакто стандарт в java). Я прочитал коменты под вопросом, а там есть предположения (очень неправильные), что если транзакции, то бизнес логика обязательно должна быть в БД, вот и решил написать. Но, похоже, зря сунулся в .net :)

Comment: @RomanKonoval А, понял. Ну тогда ладно, так можно.

Comment: @tym32167 я согласен, что "без усилий" это я загнул. Я глянул, в EF core unit of work вроде как [из коробки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/). Может не туда смотрю.

Comment: по идее да, но проьблема у автора в том, что у него вызовы EFCore закрыты репозиториями, репозитории закрыты сервисными классами. То есть на уровне бизнес логики у него сохранение выглядит как вызов одного сервиса. потом вызов другого. То есть, из коробки у него получится 2 транзакции. Хз как сейчас, я на дотнетах не пишу давненько, но раньше такое решалось 0) закидиванием всего фнкционала в один сервис / репозиторий 1) общим контекстом за запрос через DI 2) Использованием TransactionScope 3) написнием своего UoW 4) переходом на какой нить CQRS/Mediatr